# Android how to display tabs in all activities when using lazylist viewer

Tags: android

I have implemented the lazy list image viewer using simple list adapter. The problem I am facing now is that I am unable to implement multiple activities under same tab on the Lazy list.
for lazy list I referred to this tutorial

From my ACtivity1 after retrieving the JSON data using async the data is sent to the listview adapter.

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {

    listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.view);

    adapter = new ListViewAdapter(class.this, arraylist);

    listview.setAdapter(adapter);

    mProgressDialog.dismiss();
}
```

mylist adapter is as follows

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    // -------------Some code ----------------------------

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, SingleItemView.class);

    context.startActivity(intent);

}
```

in list view adapter class I have set up an `onclick` event which takes the user to a new activity to view the single item

now the problem is that I amm unable to get the tab view on this `singleitemview` activity

I saw a this [tutorial](http://gamma-point.com/content/android-how-have-multiple-activities-under-single-tab-tabactivity) to implement the multiple activities in same tab but couldn't figure out how to implement this in my app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ActivityGroup implementation referenced in the tutorial is deprecated.

The recommended approach is to implement a single activity with multiple fragments. To achieve this, you can use a ViewPager, for which there is nice tutorial here;
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/lateral.html

You are going to need the Android support v4 library for this, which you can add to your project by right clicking on your project in eclipse > Android Tools > Add support library.